# Linq left join null reference error

Tags: c#, linq

When i am making left join i have this error. How to prevent error if id's doenot intersect?

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Component> firstlist = new List<Component>();
        List<Component> secondlist = new List<Component>();
        firstlist.Add(new Component { id = 1, Name = "Jhon" });
        secondlist.Add(new Component { id = 2, Name = "Jhon" });

        var test = from d in firstlist
                                 join i in secondlist
                                 on d.id equals i.id
                                 into a
                                 from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new Component { id = b.id, Name = b.Name };
        List<Component> Result = test.ToList();
    }

    public class Component
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is it caused by `b`? You may want to check if `b` is not `null`

Comment: Yes it cause by b. Hot to fix it in linq?

Comment: Either add a `where b != null` or really don't do a left join since you only pull values from the right.  Really it depends on what you expect, an empty list or a list that contains `null` items or `Component`s with default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Component> firstlist = new List<Component>();
        List<Component> secondlist = new List<Component>();
        firstlist.Add(new Component { id = 1, Name = "Jhon" });
        secondlist.Add(new Component { id = 2, Name = "Jhon" });

        var test = from d in firstlist
                                 join i in secondlist
                                 on d.id equals i.id
                                 into a
                                 from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new Component { id = (b != null) ?b.id : default(int), Name = (b != null) ? b.Name : default(string) };
        List<Component> Result = test.ToList();
    }

    public class Component
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added a null check on b before setting it.

```
select new Component { id = (b != null) ? b.id : default(int), Name = (b != null) ? b.Name : default(string) };
```

You might also be able to do something like

```
select (b == null) ? default(Component) : new Component { id = b.id, Name = b.Name };
```

I'm not 100% sure about the syntax for that second option, but something like that might work.

Comment: In C# 6 you could do `new Component { id = b?.id ?? 0, Name = b?.Name }`

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, you need to ensure that `b` is not `null` before you call/use its method/property/field. Change this:

```
select new Component { id = b.id, Name = b.Name };
```

into:

```
select new Component { id = b == null ? 0 : b.id, Name = b == null ? null : b.Name };
```

In C#6, you could use null conditional operator `?.`:

```
select new Component { id = b?.id ?? 0, Name = b?.Name };
```

Comment: the `id = b?.id` will not work because `id` is an `int` and `b?.id` would return an `int?`.  So you really need something like `id = b?.id ?? 0`.

Comment: @juharr you are right, thanks for the correction. `id` is `int`

Answer (score 0):

you problem lies in

```
select new Component { id = b.id, Name = b.Name };
```

using a.DefaultIfEmpty() can return NULL, and so b.id will throw exception. 
Correct code should be:

```
select new Component { id = b==null?return_safe_value:b.id, Name =b==null?rturn_safe_value:b.Name };
```